# In Chrome Developer Tools, how can I disable the highlight around elements that refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, developer-tools

In a ReactJS application, I have the `Chrome Developer Tools` open

When I click on something I can see highlight around elements that refresh.

How can I disable the highlight so I can use the iPhoneX emulator without ugly highlight everywhere all the time?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's been changed at `devtools v4`, asked at `Aug 17, 2019` and updated at `Oct 3, 2019`

(For React version < 15, use `devtools v3` instead)

### [image]

Refer:

- related issue: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16437
- related PR: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/16989

---

This is how you do:

1. `F12` to open the developer tools
2. Click on the `Components` tab
3. Within the react tree, on the upper right corner, click on the settings icon
4. Click on `General tab`
5. Uncheck `Highlight updates when components render`